# Adding custom HTTP header field for all UIWebView requests

Tags: ios, swift, webview, header, http-headers

I'm using the below code to set a custom HTTP header on requests sent from my UIWebView. The problem is a syntax error when coding with swift3
Is it possible to modify with swift3?

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    let headerFields = request.allHTTPHeaderFields
    var headerIsPresent = contains(request.allHTTPHeaderFields?.keys.array as [String], "X-Test-App")

    if headerIsPresent || navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.Other {
        return true
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                let url = request.URL
                var newRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = request as NSMutableURLRequest
                // set new header
                newRequest.addValue("MyValue", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Test-App")

                // reload the request
                self.webView.loadRequest(newRequest)
            })
        })
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
Syntax error in this section...